# Editing Java Function Apps is not supported in the Azure portal error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, cloud, serverless

So, when I am trying to create a *function* inside a ***function app*** it shows `Editing Java Function Apps is not supported in the Azure portal.`

The *Add* button is not working and only local development option is present.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it seems that we cannot create `Java Function` on `Azure portal`, because creating `Java Function` requires `Maven` or `Gardle`, but `Azure portal` does not seem to contain them.

So we can only develop `Java Function` locally and then deploy them to the `Azure portal`.

If you want to get this feature, you can go to the [Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) page to post your thoughts, and the Azure development team may adopt your suggestions.

By the way, not only `Java`, only script programming languages can be added to `Azure Portal`. In other words, `Azure Portal` can only create functions that use languages that do not require compilation

You might say that `C#` can be created directly on `Azure portal`, but the `c# function` created in `Azure Portal` is actually the [c# script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp).